# Proposals For Canonical Questions

Tags: discussion

Finding myself with a large amount of free time would like to find out from some of the other members here what questions members are finding asked frequently that could benefit from canonical questions.

I am not asking for proposals for catch all questions to cover the whole scope of a single subject rather specific questions which seem to be asked over and over again with little variation where mod's and regular users of the site feel a single canonical question would be able to deal with the repetition.

Comment: We get tons of questions about 404 errors that show up in Google Search Console.

Answer (score 1):

From memory when I was more active on this site. We kept seeing questions about:

- htaccess redirects
- multi-lingual sites
- SEO (good look with writing a canonical question!)
- crawling issues (when it takes place)

Also, look at the discussion on catch-all questions: https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/catch-all